# Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute

Tags: cookies, paypal-sandbox, mern, samesite

I'm using PayPal payment button with my Mern app , i used the typical sandbox accounts of after configuration. the first time it worked perfectly and after that it doesn't want to pay and lighthouse is send me this error

Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute
Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being set in a cross-site context. This behavior protects user data from accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests.

server.js

```
import express, { application } from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import colors from 'colors';
import { notFound, errorHandler } from './middleware/errorMiddleware.js';
import connectDB from './config/db.js';
import productRoutes from './routes/productRoutes.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import orderRoutes from './routes/orderRoutes.js';
import uploadRoutes from './routes/uploadRoutes.js';

dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running..');
});

app.use('/api/products/', productRoutes);
app.use('/api/users/', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/orders', orderRoutes);
app.use('/api/upload', uploadRoutes);
app.get('/api/config/paypal', (req, res) => res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID));

app.use(notFound);

app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} on port ${PORT}`.red.bold));
```

orderScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
//import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from '@paypal/react-paypal-js';
import { PayPalButton } from 'react-paypal-button-v2';

import { useParams, Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import Message from '../components/Message';

import { getOrderDetails, payOrder, deliverOrder } from '../actions/orderActions.js';
import { ORDER_PAY_RESET, ORDER_DELIVER_RESET } from '../constants/orderConstants.js';


const OrderScreen = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const orderId = `${id}`;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useLocation();
  const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails;

  const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay);
  const { loading: loadingPay, success: successPay } = orderPay;

  const orderDeliver = useSelector((state) => state.orderDeliver);
  const { loading: loadingDeliver, success: successDeliver } = orderDeliver;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  if (!loading) {
    //   Calculate prices
    const addDecimals = (num) => {
      return (Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    };
    order.itemsPrice = addDecimals(order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      history('/login');
    }

    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
      const { data: clientId } = await axios.get('/api/config/paypal');
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`;
      script.async = true;
      script.onload = () => {
        setSdkReady(true);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    if (!order || successPay || successDeliver || order._id !== orderId) {
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_RESET });
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_RESET });
      dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId));
    } else if (!order.isPaid) {
      if (!window.paypal) {
        addPayPalScript();
      } else {
        setSdkReady(true);
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, orderId, successPay, history, userInfo, successDeliver, order]);

  const successPaymentHandler = (paymentResult) => {
    console.log(paymentResult);
    dispatch(payOrder(orderId, paymentResult));
  };

  const deliverHandler = () => {
    dispatch(deliverOrder(order));
  };

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : error ? (
    <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
  ) : (
    <>
      <h1>Order {order._id}</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Shipping</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Name: </strong> {order.user.name}
              </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Email: </strong> <a href={`mailto:${order.user.email}`}>{order.user.email}</a>
              </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Address:</strong>
                {order.shippingAddress.address}, {order.shippingAddress.city} {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}, {order.shippingAddress.country}
              </p>
              {order.isDelivered ? <Message variant='success'>Delivered on {order.deliveredAt}</Message> : <Message variant='danger'>Not Delivered</Message>}
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Payment Method</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Method: </strong>
                {order.paymentMethod}
              </p>
              {order.isPaid ? <Message variant='success'>Paid on {order.paidAt}</Message> : <Message variant='danger'>Not Paid</Message>}
            </ListGroup.Item>

            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Order Items</h2>
              {order.orderItems.length === 0 ? (
                <Message>Order is empty</Message>
              ) : (
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                  {order.orderItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col md={1}>
                          <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                          <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                          {item.qty} x ${item.price} = ${item.qty * item.price}
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  ))}
                </ListGroup>
              )}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Items</Col>
                  <Col>${order.itemsPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Shipping</Col>
                  <Col>${order.shippingPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Tax</Col>
                  <Col>${order.taxPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Total</Col>
                  <Col>${order.totalPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              {!order.isPaid && (
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  {loadingPay && <Loader />}
                  {!sdkReady ? <Loader /> : <PayPalButton amount={order.totalPrice} onSuccess={successPaymentHandler} />}
                </ListGroup.Item>
              )}

              {loadingDeliver && <Loader />}
              {userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin && order.isPaid && !order.isDelivered && (
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Button type='button' className='btn btn-block' onClick={deliverHandler}>
                    Mark As Delivered
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              )}
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default OrderScreen;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Find the best products for the cheapsest prices !" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AZm6WLwtUgFKRRvQqV6hMDWIw_CmEDavupEI2NdSImpe3oKSYXWjqBN_dfIOgCfdQ7CCDcYFE3-fx5_X"></script>

    <title>Pro Shop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store.js';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

I've tried everything yet nothing seems to fix it. Most answers show that my code is true but the problem is with my browser , I'm using brave I tried chrome and Microsoft edge. still the same.

I am aware that the problem is because the cookies are blocked but i can't figure out how to fix it !

Comment: Is your app served from a `https` (as opposed to just `http`) Web origin?

Comment: im using http://localhost:3000/ and the sandbox is using https

Comment: What is using `http://localhost:3000` exactly? Your frontend?

Comment: my frontend uses http://localhost:3000 and my back uses http://localhost:5000 also added this to frontend  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",